# Improve performance for returning value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How to improve perfomance for G(x,y) for this type of evaluation structure:

```
from scipy import integrate,infty

def f(x):
    """
    Some complicated function
    """
    pass

def F(x):
    """
    Integration of f
    """
    value = integrate.quad(f,-infty,x)
    return value

def g(x,y):
    """
    Another complicated function which uses F(x)!
    """
    pass    

def G(x,y):
    """
    The function for which I want to improve perfomance
    """
    value = integrate.quad(g,-infty,+infty,args=(y))
    return value
```

What I want is to substitute F(x) evaluation with its reference to it which have been done previously.

### Edit

After of using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and decorator for clarity, my code looks like:

```
class interpolate_function():
    """
    Returns interpolated function in given range
    """
    def __init__(self,tmin=-20,tmax=+20):

        self.tmin = tmin
        self.tmax = tmax

    def __call__(self,expX):

        tmin = self.tmin
        tmax = self.tmax

        from numpy import linspace
        t = linspace(tmin,tmax,2000)

        import scipy.interpolate as inter
        #expX_interp = inter.PchipInterpolator(t,W.expX(t))
        from scipy import vectorize

        expX = vectorize(expX)
        expX_interp = inter.interp1d(t,expX(t),kind='linear')

        return expX_interp


from scipy import integrate,infty

def f(x):
    """
    Some complicated function
    """
    pass

@interpolate_function(tmin=-20,tmax=+20)
def F(x):
    """
    Integration of f
    """
    value = integrate.quad(f,-infty,x)
    return value

def g(x,y):
    """
    Another complicated function which uses F(x)!
    """
    pass    

def G(x,y):
    """
    The function for which I want to improve perfomance
    """
    value = integrate.quad(g,-infty,+infty,args=(y))
    return value
```

Therefore the main code except decorator remains unchanged but performance is boosted around 3000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every call to `F(x)`, you are doing an integration in (-infinity, x), that is your bottleneck. Instead, I would perform the integration to a set of points and create an interpolating function. So, if your values of `x` are between 0 and 10, you can perform the integrals from -infinity to 0, 0.5... 9.5, 10 (as thin grid as you need) and interpolate on them.

**Edit:**

In order to build the grid more efficiently, you can use the additive properties of the integrals. So, F(0) = int_infty^0 f(x), F(1) = F(0) + int_0^1 f(x), etc. You can use different sizes for the grid, as long as you keep track of them. Also, to be safe from weird interpolating effects, I would use `pchip` (Hermite polinomials, always reach maximum and minimum in the borders) or linear interpolation.

Comment: Seems interpolation is the key for solving my problem, but why exactly evaluation of interpolated data could be faster? The x values are from -infinity to 100 and it is known that F(x) does not changes much for large negative values. How to choose the sample?

Comment: `F(4.5)` involves many evaluations of `f(x)` between -infinity and 4.5; but the interpolated function requires only one polinomial evaluation.

Comment: got it ;) Now I need to choose the sample. Are there any adaptive methods (smaller steps for faster changing function) available? For -infinity the -100 could be great approximation.

Comment: Not that I can think of, except rolling your own. You could chime in the mailing list if you want to create a indefinite integral. Also, replacing infinity by a fixed number can be a very good performance (and in some cases, accuracy) boost.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pchip which is exactly what I need for doing experimental data interpolation :) However from performance perspective linear interpolation is around 100 times economical.

Comment: Pchip gives better values, but as you mention, does more job. In fact, you can run it twice with one method each. The difference on the final result should give you a rough estimation of the error introduced by interpolation (assuming your sampling decently represents your data, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is ["memoization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), using a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators):

```
def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def func(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return func

@memo
def F(x):
    """
    Integration of f
    """
    value = integrate.quad(f,-infty,x)
    return value
```

Now whenever you call `F(x)`, you are really calling `func(x)`, and if `F` has already been evaluated for that value of `x` it is returned straight from the `cache`, rather than calling `F` again.

Note that, as Davidmh points out, this trades speed for space; you have to store all of the previously-evaluated results. Also, you only get a benefit where you are evaluating exactly the same value of `x` multiple times.

Comment: This will only work if the values of x repeat themselves, and for float numbers that is unlikely. Also, you will increase memory unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for idea of using decorator in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the key to optimizing for efficiency in numpy/scipy is to minimize the amount of python code execution. If at all possible, any loops should not be done as python loops, but as matrix-vector operations or similar; essentially, you want to move loops to within numpy/scipy libraries.

In your case, I would try to avoid calling other python functions from `g` and try to write it as a short series of numpy/scipy calls.